# How to run electron as root

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I try to run electron on may kali linux as where I am the root but it doesn't show anything but it works on my ubuntu where I am not the root.

When I run: npm run electron:start

I get this:

11640:0227/233443.028885:FATAL:atom_main_delegate.cc(211)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

help me please.

Comment: What version of Electron are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to do it without being **root**. And until then for it to work when you execute the command "

> npx cap open electron

", you must locate the directory of the chrome-sandbox file in the error message where you will have to execute the following two commands:

```
sudo chown root: root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

Generally, here is what I do to use ionic and electron on **Kali linux**:

```
1. npm install ngx-electron electron
2. npm install electron-packager --save-dev
3. ionic build
4. npx cap add electron
5. ionic build && npx cap copy
6. npx cap open electron
```

You can see here for more explanation:
https://gist.github.com/gnopor/d4813628c949294c4ef8b4ef88941f68